# namespace error in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

[this is a sample page from files of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm8j6.png)

namespace cake\Controller;

use cake\Controller\AppController;

both of these lines shows red in dreamweaver

Comment: Is there any error message being displayed?

Comment: No it does not shows any error

Comment: I think it should be namespace App\Controller; use App\Controller\AppController

Answer (score 1):

In cakephp all controllers are in namespace `App\Controller` and use `App\Controller\AppController`, since `AppController` is the default and all other controllers extend it.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
}
```

Comment: But, this App will be overriden by my app name is this the case? or I hv to keep it as it is in my controller as App\Controller

Comment: For cakephp's (and all MVC frameworks) URL handler to work properly you need to extend the default controller and yes this will provide an override method to  for each action, but this is how most MVC's work.

Comment: My Question was about the first two lines of my code which is showing red in my editor(dreamweaver).

Comment: Misread your previous comment. You will not override your app name, as this is another convention in cakephp -> in your application folder there is a folder named 'app' and in it another folder named 'controller'. So, namespaces in this case show where the files are for the autoloader to find them and load them.

Comment: There is no folder named `app`, that's what CakePHP 1/2 looked like. CakePHP 3 by default places application code in the `src` folder, which is being mapped to the `App` base namespace. @eager I think you better start with studying some PHP namespace basics before trying to tackle a framework like CakePHP.